# Word that means "bad news"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The expression is so common I thought there was a word for it.

I was surprised to find none on [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bad%20news) (none of the words are related to "giving new information").

Is there any word for "bad news"?

Comment: We often use expressions like "I'm sorry to tell you that... " or "I regret to inform you that ...".  Or use a different adjective like "unfortunate news" or "regrettable news" or "tragic news".

Comment: There are so many English phrases that don't have a single word. It doesn't have a single word for "handsome face", 'beautiful face", "long hand", "short hand", etc. Why does it have to have a word for "bad news"?

Comment: @Rathony Curiously, there's godspell for good news, but your point is well taken. "Bad news" is already powerful.
Bad news, bad news to England doth flow
Bad news  I have to tell thee
For there's been a rich merchant ship, and for England was bound
Have sunk to the bottom of the sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [*bad
>   news*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bad_news): A
>   person or thing that is regarded as unpleasant, unlucky, or
>   undesirable.
>
> **Synonyms:**
>
> - unpleasant, disagreeable, unwelcome, unfortunate, unfavourable, unlucky, adverse, nasty
> - terrible, dreadful, awful, grim, distressing, regrettable